# testing-library/user-event - how to handle `act(...)` warnings related to material-ui's animations?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, user-event

I understand that I'm not supposed to add `act()` around user events because the testing library does it for me, but I get warnings if I don't.  Specifically, for example given a MUI component with the ripple effect, here's what I find:

```
import { Tab as MuiTab } from "@mui/material";

describe("Tab", () => {

    it("MuiTab creates a warning ", async () => {
        const user = userEvent.setup();
        render(<MuiTab label="hello" />);

        // yep.  There's a warning here.
        await user.click(screen.getByRole("tab"));
    });

    it("MuiTab does NOT create a warning with disableTouchRipple", async () => {
        const user = userEvent.setup();

        // disabling the animation fixes the warning
        render(<MuiTab label="hello" disableTouchRipple />);

        await user.click(screen.getByRole("tab"));
    });

    it("MuiTab does NOT create a warning with act", async () => {
        const user = userEvent.setup();
        render(<MuiTab label="hello" />);

        // no warning
        await act(async () => await user.click(screen.getByRole("tab")));
    });
});
```

These warnings started when I upgraded `@testing-library/react` to `^14.0.0`, which fixed other `act` warnings.

But now with the upgrade, I have 1.7M lines of warnings in my test suite.  It's not "wrong" in that the ripple effect hasn't ended by the end of the test and I also understand that using jest timers can help resolve this.

*But it feels wrong to add `act` throughout the testing suite or to litter my test code with fake timers just because MUI has some animations.*

**Given all that, what's the recommended way for me to fix these warnings?**

Versions:

- "@mui/material": "^5.12.1"
- "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
- "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
- "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
- "jest": "^29.5.0"

*(Also, please don't tell me that I should be asserting on the expected behavior after the click. I know that. I'm just using the `Tab` as an example and I get the warnings whether there's an `expect` afterwards or not.)*

Comment: In tests, React needs to understand that certain actions will cause component updates. React testing library already wraps some of its APIs in `act`. But in some cases, you still need to use `waitFor`, `waitForElementToBeRemoved`, or `act` to tell the test: *"I'm expecting the component to update here"*. Consider reading [this](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning), [this](https://davidwcai.medium.com/491a5629193b), [this](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/).

Comment: Thanks.  I've actually read all of those articles and this question comes after a lot of research.  I'm sorry you didn't like my comments on your answer, and I can only assume that the downvote and the link to the meta question is in response.
As said in my question, I have 1.7 million lines of warnings that just showed up with an upgrade, and adding `act` or `waitFor` around every single animation (which I don't control) does not seem like the right solution.

Comment: You're correct in assuming I downvoted, but you're a bit off about the reasons. First of all, I should have downvoted your question earlier, as it didn't contain any research effort. You're supposed to document all relevant research effort. The other reason is you're not looking for a correct solution, but for one that *"seems right"* (whatever that means). In essence, you're asking for opinionated advice, preferably  one which supports your own feelings regarding your own code-base, not for factual based answers. And that's *off-topic*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The root cause ended up being that npm resolved version dependencies of `@testing-library/dom` incorrectly.

This took a lot of time to figure out. Specifically, I would tweak the `package.json` and pin specific versions, then run `npm install && npm run test &> output##-version-details.log` so that I could track what happened with each change.  When I started seeing conflicts in my output is when I looked at the `package-lock.json` changes.  By leveraging git I could then start easily compare `package-lock.json` files.

Where `@testing-library/react` wanted `@testing-library/dom` as `^9.0.0`, what npm had actually resolved was `8.20.0`.  I don't know why -- the package.json did not specify a dom version.

Once `@testing-library/react` was using the correct dom version, the bulk of the warnings went away.

*The upgrade also resulted in 7 new test failures out of ~950 tests, but those should be easy to resolve.*

---

#### Regarding wrapping all user input in `act()` or `waitFor()`

While I don't have specific evidence, I read a number of reports about `waitFor` suppressing error messages.  It doesn't make sense to `waitFor` a click event since there's nothing identifiable for the library to say "yes, okay, it's done".  I suspect that it "works" because it's suppressing the warnings and/or just a stand-in for wrapping it in another `act()` directly.

On that note, wrapping events in `act()` seemed like it should have been superfluous since `testing-library` already wraps user events in `act`.  And when I did start adding it through my test suite, I started getting the `Warning: The current testing environment is not configured to support act(...)` error in some cases.

Hence none of the documentation on react testing library nor my own experiences indicated to me this was the "right" solution.

---

#### Regarding configuring MUI

This was a dead-end.

Before I figured out the package issue, I also spent a lot of time trying to disable the `TouchRipple` effect in MUI and transitions in MUI.  This resulted in ~20K warning lines reduced total, but it also resulted in more failed tests, too.  I might go back later and disable `TouchRipple` just because it's not necessary for tests.

[source for globally disabling](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-disable-the-ripple-effect-globally)

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';

const themeOverrides = createTheme({
  transitions: {
    // So we have `transition: none;` everywhere
    create: () => 'none',
  },
  components: {
    // Name of the component ⚛️
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The props to apply
        disableRipple: true, // No more ripple, on the whole application !
      },
    },
  },
});
## Then use the new these in a ThemeProvider for your tests.  
## You can nest themes.
```